# I have an error when compiling android Q kernel

Tags: android, compilation, kernel

I have this error:`CROSS_COMPILE_ARM32 not defined or empty, the compat vDSO will not be built` when i trying to compile android kernel. My phone is aarch64, and i don't know, how to fix it, because i'm using clang. 
I need to use arm32 toolchain?
i'm using this:`

```
PATH="<path to clang folder>/bin:<path to gcc folder>/bin:${PATH}" \
make -j$(nproc --all) O=out \
                      ARCH=arm64 \
                      CC=clang \
                      CLANG_TRIPLE=aarch64-linux-gnu- \
                      CROSS_COMPILE=aarch64-linux-android-`
```